# Best settings for pork shoulder instant pot recipe?

Tags: instant-pot

Help!

I have a slow cooker recipe with pork shoulder... recipe calls for 3 lbs pork and 2c chicken broth, 4 hours on high or 8 hours low.

I put in extra meat (5 lb total) and about 3c chicken broth, and I'm slow cooking it but I started it too late for lunch. It's been going for 2hrs on high. I want to switch to pressure cook - how long and what settings should I use? I have about an hour left before we need to eat.

Thanks

Comment: My rule of thumb is 1/8th the time in pressure as with slow-cooking on low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

End result:
I pressure cooked it on high for 12 minutes, then after checking it I cooked it again for another 2 minutes. It probably could have used a little bit longer but it came out OK.

Comment: Did you get to just properly cooked through or all the way to falling apart as one would get from a slow cooker after the full time?

Comment: Just cooked through. It wasn't quite as tender as we got from the slow cooker, I think, but it was still good